# Java caching solution needed

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm looking for a caching solution for a Java Web Application. We have an Oracle db instance and 2-3 instances that are remote to our db.
We want to cache data locally to our app as we can't accept db response time. 
Our dataset is of average size (few thousands of row per table) and is modified manually (so not very often) from our application (no direct db access).

So what we've been thinking of is a solution that allows us to have all data that's needed locally. We'd like to reduce the amount of data being retrieved from db and rewritten to cache.

So for example, when one entity is modified, we don't want to invalidate all cached queries on that table, we'd rather want to be able to modify locally cached queries resultsets so query still can be run locally from cached data. 
Caches have to replicate their changes\retrieve data modified by other instances of application from db.

We've been looking at EhCache as a Hibernate 2nd level cache but it invalidates all cached queries for given table on any table modification. I took a quick look into Hibernate Services but don't know yet if that would allow us to override hibernate 2nd level cache default behavior to meet our needs.

Are there any other solutions that we could use?

**Edit** We want to have a very fast access to data. Effectively what we're looking for is a quaryable cache.

Comment: Why not create a local database and replicate it to the remote? It will avoid any code changes aside from your connection string, provide greater speed and ensure data consistency with your remote db.

Comment: Are you suggesting a DB instance per Application instance? seems like a lot of setup overhead to me.

Comment: No - run a full copy of the database on a local server/virtual machine, and then replicate it to the remote - in a master/slave relationship.

Comment: You are still not caching any of the data at the application layer, that approach requires always reading from DB for any request being processed. I think the idea is to avoid incurring the penalty of hitting the DB every time.

Comment: I think we will need the OP to clarify - I took `we can't accept db response time` to mean the remote db is slow, and therefor impacting application performance, and `So what we've been thinking of is a solution that allows us to have all data that's needed locally. We'd like to reduce the amount of data being retrieved from db and rewritten to cache. ` to mean that they do not want to rely on a caching solution as the only option. @Bart - Can you clarify which option you're looking for?

Comment: We want to have a very fast access to data. Effectively what we're looking for is a quaryable cache.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out JBoss cache? You can define the eviction policies for your queries separately and also its very easy to sync between your cluster nodes. If you need you can read up on the article i compiled some time back on my experience if it is helpful for you ;

http://dinukaroshan.blogspot.com/2009/10/jboss-caching-integration.html

Comment: Can use of JBoss change a default hibernate 2nd level cache behavior of invalidating all cached queries on a table every time there is any modification done? Standard hibernate 2nd level cache doesn't meet our needs as a query cache only makes sense for static data.

Comment: Hi Bart, Usually the rule of thumb is to cache data that rarely change but is often read (e.g master data).. I am not sure about if you can change the invalidation rules.. but will check up and get back to you..

Answer (score 2):

If you use EhCache and you have multiple application in clusters, you will have to use a mechanism (JMS, JGroups,...) for the data cache replication.

One thing you must be aware is that if you have another application not running in Java, the app won't be notified: JGroups is only available in Java and your non-Java app won't be able to invalidate a cached entity. The EhCache/Jgroups support allow you to set up the replication in ONE configuration file (no additional code require!)

It seems that you are looking for the "Update via Copy" feature of EhCache. Let me list one the configuration possibilities of EhCache:

**Update via Copy vs Invalidation**

**Update Via Copy**: Data sent to all nodes
 
Pros: Avoid a complete re-load of the cache
 
Cons: Incoherent data between nodes is possible & useless if the TTL of the cached data is low

**Update via invalidation**: Notification of invalidation sent to all nodes. If the data are already cached, nodes remove cached data query again the database.
 
Pros: Data consistency & Lighter in network traffic
 
Cons: Lot of database queries and it may result in a massive demand of data simultaneously

---

**Async vs Sync**

**Async**
 
Pros: quick reply & and data transmission
 
Cons: UDP...

**Sync**
 
Pros: Data integrity
 
Cons: Perf...

---

I hope it helped you to pick the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

The invalidation of cached query result isn't something the cache does control, but is how Hibernate handles his QueryCache... Short of changing that code, I don't see how you'd do that. And besides, I don't think there is a better "suits all" solution to that problem frankly.

So if you want *very* specialized caching of query result, I guess you'd have to implement that yourself.

Also, if you need higher consistency guarantees, you probably will want to use clustered caches, rather than a replicated one...